# How do I use react-beautiful-dnd with a lightning web component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, locker-service

I want to use the [react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd) library in a lightning web component.

This worked in the past with aura but it does not work with lightning web components.  Why would this be?  Is this prevented by lightning locker perhaps?

Comment: when you say that it worked with aura, what was the api version of the component? depending on this, yes it can be related to locker service

Comment: The api version was 44.0.  Since then I have moved to 48.0 and this library has stopped working.

Comment: i believe locker service is enforced starting api v 36 (or around there) so, changing from aura to lwc should not have impacted functionality. You should probably include a minimal code sample comparing both to get feedback